# Can one force there to be an elementary embedding $j:V_{\lambda}\rightarrow V_{\lambda}$ for some inaccessible $\lambda$?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Is it consistent that there exists an inaccessible cardinal $\lambda$ and a forcing extension $V[G]$ so that $$V[G]\models\text{There is some non-trivial elementary embedding $j:V_{\lambda}^{V[G]}\rightarrow V_{\lambda}^{V[G]}$}?$$

Any such forcing extension $V[G]$ will force the cofinality of $\lambda$ to be $\omega$.

Is it consistent that there exists an inaccessible cardinal $\lambda$ and a forcing extension $V[G]$ so that 
$$V[G]\models\text{There is some non-trivial elementary embedding $j:V_{\lambda+1}^{V[G]}\rightarrow V_{\lambda+1}^{V[G]}$}?$$

What if instead of having $\lambda$ be inaccessible, $\lambda$ satisfies some stronger large cardinal hypothesis? What is the consistency strength of these hypotheses?

Comment: When you say $j:V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$, you mean $V_\lambda^V$ right?

Comment: Do you mean that the image of the embedding is $V_\lambda$ itself, right?

Comment: Victoria. I meant $V_{\lambda}^{V[G]}$ to make it look like an I3 and a I1 cardinal. Asaf. I simply put the quotes there to specify the statement that $V[G]$ models, but I now removed them so that they do not cause confusion. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You didn't answer my question; but I guess that the answer is "yes".

Comment: Asaf. I meant that in $V[G]$ there is an I3 elementary embedding from  $V_{\lambda}^{V[G]}$ to $V_{\lambda}^{V[G]}$.

Comment: Does this mean that the forcing must at the least make $\lambda$ have cof $\omega$?

Comment: Victoria. Yes. We force the cofinality $\lambda$ to be $\aleph_{0}$.

Comment: @JosephVanName. Don't I1 cardinals in V already imply the existence of many I3 cardinals below? If we use a small partial order, these I3 cardinals are preserved to the generic extension. More specifically, if $\lambda$ is I1, then there is a $\bar{\lambda}$ below it and a $j$ a witnessing that it is I3. If $G\subset P$ is generic and $|P|<crit(j)$, then $j$ extends in the generic extension to a non-trivial elementary embedding $k$ from $V_{\bar{\lambda}}^{V[G]}$ to itself. A similar argument gives the same for I1, assuming I0.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your question. Are you asking for an inaccessible above an I3 which is itself not I3, that you can collapse and find a non-trivial embedding in the generic extension? Or do you want an inaccessible (or perhaps something stronger), not necessarily above an I3 that you can singularize through forcing and introduce an embedding in the generic extension? Or maybe something else altogether?

Comment: Everett Piper. I am asking for an inaccessible cardinal $\lambda$ so that after forcing $\lambda$ becomes a singular strong limit cardinal of cofinality $\aleph_{0}$ and in the generic extension there is an elementary embedding from $V_{\lambda}$ to $V_{\lambda}$ which may be possible since $\lambda$ is after forcing a strong limit cardinal of countable cofinality. Are the questions that I asked clearly stated or should I reword them?

Comment: @JosephVanName. Your question is vague (to me at least) but now I think I get what you are after. The point of my first comment was that the consistency of an I0 gives an I1 with your embedding in a generic extension, similarly I1 suffices for an I3 with that property. These embedding already exist in the ground model and are preserved to the generic extension. This is one direction of the Levy-Solovay phenomenon. The other direction is that large cardinals are not created in the generic extension. So your desired $\lambda$, if it is not already I3, say, then it will not become I3 in the

Comment: extension. These facts are all true at least in the case when a small forcing is used. There are large forcings which will destroy certain large cardinals, large forcings which will create so-called generic large cardinals, and, if I remember correctly, forcings that will resurrect large cardinals which were previously killed. There are many articles exhibiting this type of phenomenon, though I don't have any specific references at the moment.

Comment: @EverettPiper, I am not sure that your argument that the situation Joe wants cannot occur in a small forcing extension is accurate. Laver showed that for a fixed $\kappa$, if I3 (say) holds in a $\kappa$-small extension for $\lambda$ and $\kappa$, then there is potentially another $\lambda'$, but same $\kappa$ such that I3 holds for them in $V$. In the case $\text{cf}(\lambda)=\omega$ in $V$, $\lambda'=\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

Given Victoria's wonderful comment, I wonder if the following small forcing example is relevant to your question. The argument is from Laver's article "Certain very large cardinals are not created in small forcing extensions" (Annals of Pure and Applied Logic 149, 2007).

Call a a generic extension $V[G]$ $\kappa$-small if, in $V$, $\mathbb{P}$ has size less than $\kappa$. Laver denotes $I1$ by $E_\omega(\kappa, \lambda)$ where $\kappa$ is the critical point of the embedding $j$ and $\lambda$ is the sup of $j$'s critical sequence. $I3$ is simply $E_0(\kappa, \lambda)$ and there are intermediate hypotheses between these two extremes, denoted $E_n(\kappa, \lambda)$, where the subscript $n$ indicates that there is a non-trivial elementary embedding $j$ which is $\Sigma_{2n}^1$. Vincenzo Dimonte has some nice notes on these embeddings (and much more).

Theorem: If $V[G]$ is a $\kappa$-small extension of $V$, $n\leq\omega$, and $V[G]$ thinks there is a $\lambda$ satisfying $E_n(\kappa,\lambda)$, then $V$ thinks there is $\lambda$ satisfying $E_n(\kappa, \lambda)$.

edit: I should note that the following argument is not a proof of the theorem stated; the theorem just gives some context to the argument.

Laver notes that the embedding $k$ in $V[G]$ which witnesses $E_n(\kappa, \lambda)$ need not satisfy $k\restriction V_\lambda\in V$. There he gives an example where $\lambda$ does not have countable cofinality in $V$.

Consider the partial order which collapses $\omega_1$ and suppose $j$ witnesses $E_{n+2}(\kappa, \bar{\lambda})$. Then there are unboundedly many $\kappa'$ less than $\kappa$ with an embedding $j_{k'}$ satisfying $E_{n+1}(\kappa',\bar{\lambda})$.

Let, in $V$, $\lambda$ be the sup of the first $\omega_1$-many of the $\kappa'$s and note that this $\lambda$ has countable cofinality in the generic extension. So you can choose, in $V[G]$, an $\omega$-sequence $\kappa_0, \kappa_1, \dots$ converging to $\lambda$, along with their respective witness embeddings $\hat{j}_{\kappa_m}$ (the hat indicates that these are the lifts of the original embeddings $j_{\kappa_m}$ which live in $V$).

Using this $\omega$-sequence of lifted embeddings, you can form their inverse limit $J:V_\lambda^{V[G]}\prec V_{\bar{\lambda}}^{V[G]}$ and this is an $E_{n+1}$ embedding. Since there's a $E_n$ embedding $\hat{k}$ (the lift of $k$) on $V_{\bar{\lambda}}^{V[G]}$ there is one on $V_{\lambda}^{V[G]}$ as well.

I see no real obstacle to using the same argument (though I am cautious about such a claim): instead of $\omega_1$, collapse the first inaccessible to countable cofinality. Each critical point of any of the embeddings used is already measurable, so there are lots of inaccessibles for you to pick. If you don't want to damage the universe too much, perhaps you can even use Prikry forcing to get a $\lambda$ which is measurable in $V$ (or even a measurable limit of critical points of embeddings), but witnesses some $E_n$ in $V[G]$.

Laver's paper has lots of interesting ideas in it. If you haven't already looked at it, maybe check it out. Also, Scott Cramer has lots of good stuff on inverse limits and reflection properties of these gargantuan cardinals.

Perhaps you are familiar with all of this already. If so, have you come across some obstacle to repeating this argument in the case where your chosen $\lambda$ is an inaccessible or stronger?

Comment: Everett Piper. I was not familiar with argument yet. I will need to read up on the papers and notes that you have referenced.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, then Woodin's Σ<sub>2</sub> resurrection theorem gives examples. Assume there is a proper class of Woodin cardinals, and let φ be a Σ<sub>2</sub> statement which holds in V. Let P be any poset. There is then a poset Q in V<sup>P</sup> such that φ holds in V<sup>P*Q</sup>. P could kill all rank-in-rank embeddings, but then Q would resurrect one.

Comment: Ralf, it seems the problem is different. The question is not just whether forcing can create a rank-into-rank embedding $j\!:V_\lambda\to V_\lambda$ (which the argument you give shows it can) but whether we can do it starting with $\lambda$ an inaccessible cardinal in the ground model (which in the extension is necessarily singular of cofinality $\omega$). It is not clear in the argument you give that the witnessing $\lambda$ after forcing with your $\mathbb Q$ would be inaccessible in $V^{\mathbb P}$.

Comment: Ah, okay, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

[Double helix in large large cardinals and iteration of elementary embeddings](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2007.02.003) by Kentaro Sato proves the following:

> **Corollary 11.12.** *A critical point of a witness of $I2$ can be forced to be the $\omega$-time target of the critical point of a witness of $I3$.*

However, I have doubts about the proof.

Comment: What about the proof raises doubts?

Comment: Actually this is a theorem originally due to Martin, I think. If one Prikry forces with the normal measure associated to an I2 embedding, the critical point becomes an I3 cardinal. This should follow from results in Laver’s paper “Implications between very large cardinals.” Similarly one can Prikry force at an I1 cardinal to make it I2, which is probably due to Laver. Such things should continue to I0, and then would likely be due to Woodin and Cramer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Because the proof relies on theorem 11.10, and [an argument in the proof of  theorem 11.10 seems to prove an inconsistency](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4533622/whats-wrong-with-this-proof-that-every-rank-into-rank-cardinal-is-a-limit-of-ra), so there must be something wrong with my understanding of that proof.